# NSData Splits into chunks

Tags: objective-c, nsdata, nslog, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm NSLogging a stream of NSData that I receive back from an outside source, but for some reason, it keeps breaking itself up into 40 character chunks, and going to a new line once it hits 40 characters. I'm trying to parse through the stream and pick out values in specific places, so it's a huge hassle that it keeps jumping down a line. Does anyone know how this behavior can be prevented? Here is an example of my NSLog:

```
2013-07-17 14:44:32.638 Test App
[4041:907] data equals  <3e2c042c 31333037 31373032 34302d30 372c0100>
2013-07-17 14:44:32.698 Test App
[4041:907] data equals  <00000000 2c020000 0000002c 03000000 00002cff>
2013-07-17 14:44:32.758 Test App
[4041:907] data equals  <00000000 00>
```

**EDIT**: As for relevant code, I'm using a third party BLE library, so I figured it wouldn't be of much use. This is basically the only line of relevant code:

```
NSData *data = [BLEdevice readReceivedBytes];
NSLog(@"data equals %@", data);
```

I gave Rob's suggestion a shot, and this was the result:

```
2013-07-17 15:21:35.399 Test App[4060:907] data equals  <3e2c012c 31333037 31373033 32312d30 372cff00>
2013-07-17 15:21:35.401 Test App[4060:907] data length equals =20
2013-07-17 15:21:35.458 Test App[4060:907] data equals  <00000000>
2013-07-17 15:21:35.460 Test App[4060:907] data length equals =4
```

It should be streaming back all in just one line, rather than having a 40 character max. Maybe it is a BLE thing.

Comment: It would help if you showed some relevant code.

Comment: NSData of what? How do you get your stream? Did you put a buffer limit? When's your callback called?

Comment: @Larme It is of a third-party BLE device. I actually did put a buffer limit, its an input and output of 512 each.

Comment: @rmaddy I just posted it, my bad.

Comment: Code of readReceivedBytes? Does ReceivedData does the same that what you logged before?

Comment: That code doesn't match the log output you posted.

Comment: If you look at `NSLog(@"Data length=%d", [data length])`, it will report the actual length. `NSLog` of a `NSData`, itself, doesn't show the entire contents (e.g. imagine if the `data` was several megabytes, you wouldn't want that to be written to the console), but rather just the start of it.

Comment: BLE can only send small packets, so you're logging each packet received?

Comment: @Wain Somewhat, I'm NSLogging the entire output so that I can count down and pick out the specific bits that I need to store.

Comment: @Rob thanks man, just updated my code with the results

Comment: If BLE sends only small packets there is probably nothing you can do about it. But if you are searching for specific bytes in the stream, you should keep an `NSMutableData` object and append each chunk to it, using `appendData`.

Comment: The largest packet sent by BLE is 20bytes. In your log you see each packet as an NSData with 20 bytes hexadecimal printout, it is a BLE thing :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If BLE sends only small packets there is probably nothing you can do about it. And you
probably should not *expect* that packets of a certain size are returned.

You should collect all received chunks in an `NSMutableData` object instead:

```
// Init once:
NSMutableData *collectedData = [NSMutableData data];

// Append received data in your read loop:
NSData *data = [BLEdevice readReceivedBytes];
[collectedData appendData:data];
```

Now you can search for the specific bytes in `collectedData`.

Comment: Awesome thanks! As a side note, do you know if there is any call outside of appendData that would prevent collectedData from overwriting itself every time a new stream comes in?